# Selection.Replace me cambia la fecha

Tags: excel, vba, date

Tengo la siguiente problemática, descargo unas bases en las cuales la fecha viene en formato **`dd.mm.yyyy`**, mediante macros las ajusto, las pego y ejecuto el siguiete comando:

```
Range("K5").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Replace What:=".", Replacement:="-", LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False,        SearchFormat:=False, _
ReplaceFormat:=False
```

pero me cambia las fechas, deberían ser todas del mismo mes pero cambian así:

Antes:

[image: antes]

Despues:

[image: despues]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya encontré la solución:

```html
        Range("K5").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Replace What:=".", Replacement:="-", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
        With Selection
        .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1, 1), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, 4)
        .NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"
        End With
```

Answer (score 1):

Cuando una fecha no está en formato fecha (si te fijas en el formato de las celdas con las fechas con puntos es General) al convertirlas a fecha Excel siempre tira del formato americano, mm/dd/yyyy, hasta que se da cuenta (a partir del día 13) que lo primero no es el mes, si no el día.

Entonces del 1 al 12 del mes puede girarte las fechas. Para evitar esto, hay una función llamada `CDate()` que convierte las fechas en formato texto a formato fecha, así Excel no se puede equivocar al volcarlas a tu hoja.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MiHoja") 'cambia MiHoja por el nombre de tu hoja
        'Encuentra la última fila con datos
        Dim LastRow As Long
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row

        'Mete todo el rango con fechas en un array
        Dim arr As Variant
        arr = .Range("K2:K" & LastRow).Value

        'Recorre el array convirtiendo las fechas con "." en fechas correctas
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
            arr(i, 1) = CDate(Replace(arr(i, 1), ".", "/"))
        Next i

        'Pega el array de vuelta a la hoja
        .Range("K2:K" & LastRow).Value = arr

    End With


End Sub
```

Comment: sigue dando vuelta la fecha

Comment: En qué idioma tienes tu windows? EN(US) porque entonces sería normal.

Comment: está en español, pero ya encontré como solucionarlo, gracias de todos modos.